# Display locks when executing G-code for laser cutting using Marlin on RAMPS board

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, pronterface, laser

I'm working on a Laser cutter. I’m using the RAMPS 1.4 and Marlin software. To make the Marlin software work with a laser I’m inspired by this blog from dreammakercnc: [Marlin Firmware modification for Laser Control](http://dreammakercnc.blogspot.com/2015/06/marlin-firmware-modification-for-laser.html)

My plan is to use Inkscape to design and create the G-code. With Pronterface I will sent it to the laser cutter. My plan is to get the Marlin software to work like in this video:

.

After that I will order the laser cutting machine.

For now I have the following issue:

I'm using stepper motors. They are working when I connect to Pronterface. I can control the motors when I'm using Pronterface. But when I load a G-code file, that I designed with Inkscape, the program seems to freeze. Nothing happens. It's saying:

> locking interface.

When I unlock it and sent a manual G-code it's not working. The program thinks its working at that moment. The picture that I designed is visualized in the G-code viewer of Pronterface.

I haven't connected any extruders, fan or bed to the RAMPS 1.4. I have connected one thermistor and one endstop. Both are working well. When I upload the Marlin software there are no problems.

My thoughts:

- Is my problem that the program is waiting for the extruder to get warm?
- Is there something wrong with the G-code I’am sending to the RAMPS board?

Below I will put the info from Pronterface when I connect, the G-code that I'm using and the `configuration.h` file from the Marlin software.

```
Pronterface connecting 

Connecting...
start
Printer is now online.
echo: External Reset
Marlin 1.0.2+
echo: Last Updated: Jun  6 2019 22:04:53 | Author: (Bart,24-1-2019)
Compiled: Jun  6 2019
echo: Free Memory: 5248  PlannerBufferBytes: 1360
echo:Hardcoded Default Settings Loaded
echo:Steps per unit:
echo:  M92 X78.74 Y78.74 Z533.33 E836.00
echo:Maximum feedrates (mm/s):
echo:  M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z5.00 E25.00
echo:Maximum Acceleration (mm/s2):
echo:  M201 X9000 Y9000 Z100 E10000
echo:Acceleration: S=acceleration, T=retract acceleration
echo:  M204 S3000.00 T3000.00
echo:Advanced variables: S=Min feedrate (mm/s), T=Min travel feedrate (mm/s), B=minimum segment time (ms), X=maximum XY jerk (mm/s),  Z=maximum Z jerk (mm/s),  E=maximum E jerk (mm/s)
echo:  M205 S0.00 T0.00 B20000 X20.00 Z0.40 E5.00
echo:Home offset (mm):
echo:  M206 X0.00 Y0.00 Z0.00
echo:PID settings:
echo:   M301 P22.20 I1.08 D114.00


G-code 

Loading file: D:\output_0001.gcode
Loaded D:\output_0001.gcode, 27 lines
0.00mm of filament used in this print
The print goes:
- from 0.00 mm to 36.62 mm in X and is 36.62 mm wide
- from 0.00 mm to 49.24 mm in Y and is 49.24 mm deep
- from 0.00 mm to 0.00 mm in Z and is 0.00 mm high
Estimated duration: 0 layers, 0:03:09
```